# IE9 RC crashes on my Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I was using IE9 beta till now and installed IE9 RC today. However it starts crashing on 50% of the sites I visit. This also includes www.youtube.com.

I did not uninstall IE9 beta before installing IE9 RC. Could this be the reason?

**EDIT:** I have uninstalled IE9 RC and installed it again after restart but that has not fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would uninstall all versions of IE9, reboot and try installing RC again.

Comment: I tried this but it has not helped.

Comment: Go to Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced Tab and hit the reset button, try IE again.

Comment: That did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does this occur on pages with flash or any other plugins?
Have you tried checking memory in your computer?

I can't really have any other idea. Other apps misbehave too? (To be honest I don't really have an idea why would you want to use IE9RC if the other apps work like a charm. Like.. it only have GPU accel.. like Chrome and Firefox's latest beta. Nothing new, nothing special.)

Comment: It seems to be happening on Pages with flash. I have 3GB RAM on my machine

Comment: Try installing Square. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/square/ |